# Relationships in a Tree (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, tree, functional-programming

Binary trees with values in the leaves and nodes are defined by:

```
   data Tree a = Leaf a
                | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
     deriving (Eq, Show)
```

For example,

```
         10
        /  \
       /    \
      8      2
     / \    / \
    3   5  2   0

exTree :: Tree Int
exTree = N 10 (N 8 (H 3) (H 5))
               (N 2 (H 2) (H 0))
```

Well, I need a function called RelationshipBinaryTree, which generates a list of tuples, whose first component is an x and its second the father. In this tree,

```
relationshipBinaryTree :: Tree a -> [(a,a)]
relationshipBinaryTree exTree =  [(10,8),(8,3),(8,5),(10,2),(2,2),(2,0)]
```

Also, I need to define it in the Data.Tree hackage (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Tree.html)

I hope you can help me because I don't understand trees and graphs very well.

I have tried this

```
relationshipBinaryTree :: Tree a -> [(a,a)] 
 relationshipBinaryTree (L _) = [] 
 relationshipBinaryTree (N _ (Tree i) (Tree d)) = relationshipBinaryTree (N _) ++ relationshipBinaryTree (Tree i) ++ relationshipBinaryTree (Tree d)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you having trouble?

Comment: relationshipBinaryTree :: Tree a -> [(a,a)] ;
relationshipBinaryTree (L _) = [] ; 
relationshipBinaryTree (N _ (Tree i) (Tree d)) = relationshipBinaryTree (N _) ++ relationshipBinaryTree (Tree i) ++ relationshipBinaryTree (Tree d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it is by getting the value with an auxiliary function and then do the recursion:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a
              | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Show)


exTree :: Tree Int
exTree = Node 10 t1 t2
t1 = Node 8 (Leaf 3) (Leaf 5)
t2 = Node 2 (Leaf 2) (Leaf 0)


relationshipBinaryTree :: Tree a -> [(a,a)] 
relationshipBinaryTree (Leaf _) = [] 
relationshipBinaryTree (Node v i d) = [(v, getVal i), (v, getVal d)] ++ relationshipBinaryTree i ++ relationshipBinaryTree d

getVal (Node v _ _) = v
getVal (Leaf v) = v

   relationshipBinaryTree exTree
=> [(10,8),(10,2),(8,3),(8,5),(2,2),(2,0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `Data.Tree`, but `Data.Tree` isn't even about binary trees, but about multi way trees (a.k.a. rose trees). However, if you had a function `value :: Tree a -> a`, then of course you could map it to the children of a rose tree and combine the result with the value.

Now, there exists a function that does that in `Data.Tree`, it's called `rootLabel`. And there is another function to geht the children of a node, it's called `subForest`.

That comes from the definition of `Tree` in `Data.Tree`:

```
Node
   rootLabel :: a           -- label value
   subForest :: Forest a    -- zero or more child trees
```

So we could define for rose trees:

```
fatherChild :: Tree a -> [(a, a)]
fatherChild t = map mkPair children ++ concatMap fatherChild children
   where mkPair child = (rootLabel t, child)
         children     = subForest t
```

Example:

```
fatherChild (Node 3 [Node 8 [], Node 4 []])
> [(3,8),(3,4)]
```

Your example:

```
fatherChild (Node 10 [Node 8 [Node 3 [], Node 5 []], Node 2 [Node 2 [], Node 0 []]])
> [(10,8),(10,2),(8,3),(8,5),(2,2),(2,0)]
```

Now, this doesn't answer your question about *binary* trees, but I would like to leave that to you as an exercise, because it will be very similar (except if you get stuck). (And please don't use rose trees as binary trees, because there is no type safety to ensure that there are always two children.)